# Load debug symbols without locking the files

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, pdb-files, dbghelp

I am trying to load the debug symbols for some modules using DbgHelp without locking the PDB files so our clients can delete them while they are still loaded by us.

I've tried creating a file with the `FILE_SHARE_DELETE` flag and then calling `SymLoadModule64` with that file, but with no success:

```
// Please ignore the missing error management
void Init()
{
    // Initialize without loading the symbols
    SymInitialize(::GetCurrentProcess(), FALSE);
    ...
    // Call EnumerateSymbolsProc64 for every module
    EnumerateLoadedModules64(::GetCurrentProcess(), EnumerateSymbolsProc64, NULL);
}

BOOL WINAPI WinDbgHelpImpl::EnumerateSymbolsProc64(PTSTR moduleName, DWORD64 moduleBase, ULONG moduleSize, PVOID userContext)
{
    // Load the file with FILE_SHARE_DELETE flag
    HANDLE fileHandle = CreateFileA(moduleName,
                                    GENERIC_READ,
                                    FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE | FILE_SHARE_DELETE,
                                    0,
                                    OPEN_EXISTING,
                                    FILE_FLAG_SEQUENTIAL_SCAN,
                                    0);

    U64 res = s_winDbgHelpImpl.SymLoadModule64(::GetCurrentProcess(), fileHandle, NULL, NULL, moduleBase, moduleSize);
    DWORD err = GetLastError();

    return !(res == 0 && err != ERROR_SUCCESS);
}
```

The symbols are loaded correctly, but the files are still locked. If I stop the program before calling EnumerateLoadedModules64, I can delete the PDBs.

**Do you know if it's possible to load the symbols without locking the files?**

Comment: *"no success"* is not an error description. Does your code fail to load the file? Does it load the file, but won't let you delete it? Something else altogether? Please update your question.

Comment: @IInspectable, thanks for pointing that out, I've edited the question. If you think I should add some additional info, please let me know.